# Threads carry duplicate string objects

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Here is my code.  The log file which is created in the *startLog* method has proper count from 1 to 1000 but log file being created by *log* method has duplicate values. For example if 88 is repeated then 89 is missed and next number printed is 90. Can any one please explain why is this happening ?

```
          namespace TestThreading
            {
                public partial class Form1 : Form
                {
                    NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
                    public Form1()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                    }

                    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                    }

                    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        new Thread(startLog).Start();
                    }
                    private void startLog()
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        string str;
                        while (i < 1000)
                        {
                            str = (++i).ToString();
                            logger.Trace(str);
                            Thread t = new Thread(() => log(new TestObject(str)));
                            t.Start();
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show("Done");
                    }
                    private void log(TestObject obj)
                    {
                        logger.Debug(obj.getCount());
                    }
                }

                public class TestObject
                {
                    string count;
                    public TestObject(string i)
                    {
                        count = i;
                    }
                    public string getCount()
                    {
                        return count;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Good thing about java that it does not allow this at all. Variable must be final or effectively final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're closing over a variable (`str`) when creating your new thread and then mutating that same variable before the code can run.

Remember that closures close over *variables* not over *values.  By the time your anonymous method determines what to pass to `log` `str` has already been altered to be another value.

The solution is simple.  Just define `str` *inside* of the loop so that each closure has its own variable to close over:

```
while (i < 1000)
{
    string str = (++i).ToString();
    logger.Trace(str);
    Thread t = new Thread(() => log(new TestObject(str)));
    t.Start();
}
```

Now that variable is never being changed after it's closed over; instead a new `str` variable is created for each closure and each one has their own.

Comment: I was just writing something not too dissimilar :)

Comment: @TrevorElliott - If you'd like to clean up the duplicates, please search for one and vote to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

As Servy already answered, it is because the `str` variable is defined outside the closure

If this is needed, you can also use `ParameterizedThreadStart` and pass the variable modified within the loop. This will actually work

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        string str;
        while (i < 1000)
        {
            str = (++i).ToString();
            Thread t = new Thread((s) => Console.WriteLine(s));
            t.Start(str);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```